# Logging to Azure from on-premise site

Tags: .net, azure, logging, trace, diagnostics

I have a .net application **not** hosted in Azure. I would love to be able to read it's log and traces from a centralized place. I thought immediately of Azure Blob Storage as a good place to do so.

When inside Azure, I am familiar with enabling logging in .cscfg file:

```
Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString.
```

But in that case, the application is NOT in Azure.

Is it possible ?... i mean without going against best practices...

If yes, how to do so ?
If no, any other centralized logging and tracing system that you would recommend ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not storing logs in Azure, but we host our applications in Azure and store our logs in [Logentries.com](https://logentries.com) - great free tier, excellent analytics and works from localhost/Azure/any other location with internet you can imagine.

Answer (score 0):

I think it shouldn't be difficult to achieve this with **AZ-Copy** tool. It is resumable and resilient, IHMO with the right switches and as a scheduled task it can be a very robust solution for your purposes.

Going further into detail, I have the idea that it should be feasible to make use of that *old-fashined* 'archive' file attribute to keep track of what is pending to being uploaded, and with a simple command line delete what has already been uploaded.

---

Furthermore, in one hand, with SQL PolyBase one can afterwards make queries to the Azure Storage uploaded files as if they were on a Sql Table, or on the other hand, point Azure PowerBI to prepare a dashboard if necessary.

(In fact, I plan to do it myself when I have a bit of time for testing, I'll update this answer with my findings.)